# Prove $\dim N = \dim \rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(\mathbb{C}[G], N)$ for irreducible N

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, representation-theory

I am an undergrad who is self studying representation theory by working through Martin Isaac's Character Theory. I am trying to prove 1.17(c) just for the case of group algebras, but I need some help. Please do not give a full proof, but answer (or hint at) my specific question at the bottom. Here is the problem statement: Prove for an irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module $N$ that $\dim N$ equals the number of distinct copies of $N$ in the decomposition of $\mathbb{C}[G]$.

I learned from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100492/why-is-dimension-of-irrep-equal-to-number-of-copies-of-its-associated-submodule?rq=1) post that it is possible to prove this by showing $\dim N = \dim \rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(\mathbb{C}[G], N)$, which follows from an isomorphism $\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(\mathbb{C}[G], N)\cong N$ defined by sending all $\psi\in \rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(\mathbb{C}[G], N)$ to $\psi(1)$. This isomorphism makes sense to me. Since all $\psi\in\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(\mathbb{C}[G], N)$ are $\mathbb{C}[G]$-homomorphisms, then for all $w\in\mathbb{C}[G]$ and some $\psi(1)=n\in N$, we have $\phi(w) = w\cdot \psi(1) = w\cdot n$ which spans $N$. Each $\psi$ is therefore determined by where it sends $1$, so two homomorphisms are equal if $1$ is sent to the same place.

The next step is to construct a basis for $\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(\mathbb{C}[G], N)$, but I am confused though about what the basis of $\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(\mathbb{C}[G], N)$ looks like. I thought that we could construct a basis element $\phi_i$ by pointing out the decomposition of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ into $\bigoplus_i V_i$. Then for a set of irreducible submodules $N_1, N_2,..., N_\alpha\cong N$ represented in the decomposition $\bigoplus_i V_i$ we just define $\phi_i$ by sending the $N_i$ component of all $w\in\mathbb{C}[G]$ to its identity in $N$. Adding $\phi_i$ and $\phi_j$ together defines a homomorphism into a strict submodule of $N_i\bigoplus N_j$, so it is also a homomorphism into $N$, and this gives us the structure of a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module. My problem is, if this is how each $\phi_i$ is defined, then $\phi_i(1)$ sends $1$ to the $1$ component of $N_i$, and $\phi_j(1)$ sends $1$ to the $1$ component of $N_j$, but shouldn't these be the same element in $N$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I want to find the dimension of $\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(\mathbb{C}[G], N)$. The only way I know to do this is by explicitly forming a basis for $\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(\mathbb{C}[G], N)$. I know that $\dim N$ should equal the number of copies of $N$ in $\mathbb{C}[G]$, and I know that an isomorphism exists between $N$ and $\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(\mathbb{C}[G], N)$. So I expect to make a basis for $\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[G]}(\mathbb{C}[G], N)$, where each basis element is a function from a copy of $N$ in $\mathbb{C}[G]$ to $N$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes. Obviously they have the same dimension. As I said, the statement is "Prove for an irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$  module $N$ that $\dim N$ equals the number of copies of $N$ in $\mathbb{C}[G]$." So, I would like to show that the decomposition of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ has $\dim N$ copies of $N$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Okay, thank you for the help. I will try and complete a proof using those tools.